# How to transfer edit method of an ID to a button/links in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

This is the code in my ulrs.py

```
url(r'^viewguides/detail/(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$', views.post_update, name='update'),
```

Now I want to make it look like this:

```
<a href="/detail/(?P<id>\d+)/edit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="background-color: transparent;"><font color="Orange"> EDIT </font></a><hr>
```

So that I can edit the certain ID that I want to. But it gives me an error. How do you do it? or is there any other way? I'm new to Django.

Answer (score 1):

I just asked my colleagues who have some experience in Django. The answer is very simple.

you just need to create this function in "models.py" :

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/viewguides/detail/%s/" %(self.id)
```

and then you can call it in the html by:

```
<a href="{{obj.get_absolute_url}}edit" class="btn">EDIT</a>
```

Every time you click the btn EDIT, it will take you to the following edit page with the given id (id that contains the forms/models of the user).

Answer (score 0):

You must use the url tag in your template, something like this:

```
<a href="{% url update guide.id %}">EDIT</a>
```

Where "update" is the `name` found in urls.py and "guide" the instance you want to update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though what I meant was, i have the certain code for the edit hence if I type in the address bar "http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewguides/detail/(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$" where each id in my database contains model form (eg. title, guide, name etc), it would take me to the edit page. I'm trying to transfer that code into a button, which gives me an error because of "(?P<id>\d+)"

Comment: Well I gave you the code for the link. To make it a button, just add the `btn` class like you did before...

Comment: If you try with my code, what's not working, what do you want the template to output? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: This is what I'm referring to : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70tK2zjwM50&index=21&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQFqfCur9CJ4QnKQTVXUsRy I wanna transfer this line of code into a btn so it would go to my edit page "viewguides/detail/(?P<id>;\d+)/edit/$" instead of typing the "/edit" at every end of the line of the url. I recommend watching the video if you please.